# jquery "this" selector replacement in React.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am converting some jQuery code to React.JS, but got stuck due to jQuery "this" selector.

```
  $('.nav-cart-options-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('show');
  $(this)
    .closest('.nav-cart-options')
    .find('ul')
    .toggle();
});
```

I was able to do the toggling using React, but it is toggling all the options on individual click like this:

[image]

**But I need toggling for each drop downs like this:** 
[image]

Drop down values are coming from API, and there can be unknown number of options.

In jquery we could easily do this using `this` selector.

But I am confused how to do this in React.

My React code for reference.

```
    handleCartOptionsToggle = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, nextProps) => {
      return {
        cartOptionsToggle: !prevState.cartOptionsToggle
      };
    });
  };


    const displayBlock = {
        display: 'block'
      };



const displayNone = {
    display: 'none'
  };

  const cartOptionsUlClass = cartOptionsToggle ? displayBlock : displayNone;

<div className="nav-cart-options">
              <div
                className={cartOptionsClass}
                onClick={handleCartOptionsToggle}
              >
                Details anzeigen <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
              </div>
              <ul style={cartOptionsUlClass}>
                <li>
                  <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
                  <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
                  <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
                  <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried to do in ReactJS?

Comment: @NicolaeMaties In React.JS I created one function using which I manipulated a `state` property and based on that `state` property I changed the CSS for that block.

Comment: Please copy paste your code in here, maybe that could help in finding the solution :)

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I have edited the code and added React

Comment: Where is the onClick/onChange event for triggering `handleCartOptionsToggle`?

Comment: @NicolaeMaties check it.

Comment: `cartOptionsUIClass` should be `const cartOptionsUlClass = this.state.cartOptionsToggle ? displayBlock : displayNone;`

Comment: @NicolaeMaties that here is not the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you try to convert `$('.nav-cart-options-toggle').on('click', function() {...` to react code, you're adding `onClick` attribute in jsx to the element having class `nav-cart-options-toggle`.

`$(this)` is basically jQuery object of the target element. In your event listener function in react, you can get the current element by `event.target`. jQuery object will have additional methods available on it which you'll not get in `event.target`. You can write either plain Javascript to do it or if you can figure out some sort of binding you can apply though react.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the current element from `event.target` but if I do it like that, it will be like directly manipulating the DOM, that I don't want that.

Comment: In that case you'll have to refactor or re-architecture your code in to use `react` way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this.

```js
class Dropdowns extends React.PureComponent {
  handleCartOptionsToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
        cartOptionsToggle: !this.state.cartOptionsToggle
    });
  };

  render() {
    const cartOptionsUlClass = { display: this.state.cartOptionsToggle ? 'block': 'none' }
    return (<div className="nav-cart-options">
      <div
        className={cartOptionsClass}
        onClick={this.handleCartOptionsToggle}
      >
        Details anzeigen <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      </div>
      <ul style={cartOptionsUlClass}>
        <li>
          <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
          <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
          <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong className="label">PRODUKT:</strong>
          <span className="values">vorne (detailliert)</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: This code was okay, if there was only one block of code. But the `<div className="nav-cart-options">` will come multiple times.

Comment: You might need to inject this component wherever you want the dropdowns, make this component do one thing, handle a single dropdown which toggles, receives the data to display in the dropdown. Inject this dropdown component wherever you want a new dropdown.